# For each integer a>1, is there an integer power p such that the decimal expansion of $a^p$ contains the digit 0?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This isn't homework, but I'm trying to work some other math problems for fun in my spare time, and noticed that I had trouble solving this slightly adjacent question. I've noticed that the ways we can get a 0 in a decimal expansion is either a) with no carry-in through 2*5, 4*5, or 5*6, or b) with a carry-in through basically any other product of numbers, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be unknown: https://oeis.org/A071531 (but for $a \leq 10000$ the answer is yes and smallest such $p\leq 10$ in all these cases)

Comment: We can safely assume that this is true, proving it is however another story.

Comment: In fact, it is likely the case that for each such $a$ there is $N$ such that all $a^p$ for $p \ge N$ contain $0$: see [OEIS sequence A020665](http://oeis.org/A020665).  Again, however, no proof is in sight.

Comment: I am slightly confused although this probably does not really change the answer. Must $p$ be a perfect power or is it an arbitary integer ?

Comment: @Peter I think $p$ is just a positive integer. Of course $a^p$ is a perfect power, for $p>1.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four cases.

**Case 1:** $a$ is divisible by $10$. Then $p=1$ works.

**Case 2:** $a$ is not divisible by $2$ or by $5$. Then $p=40$ works: by Euler's theorem, $a^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$, so the second digit from the end of $a^{40}$ is $0$.

**Case 3:** $a = 2^b \cdot c$, where $c$ is not divisible by $2$ or by $5$. Then $p=40\,000$ works. First, we check that $2^{40\,000} \equiv 9\,376\pmod{100\,000}$. Next, we check that $9\,376^2 \equiv 9\,376 \pmod{100\,000}$; it follows that $(2^b)^{40\,000} \equiv 9\,376^b \equiv 9\,376 \pmod{100\,000}$ by induction. Meanwhile, $c^{40\,000} \equiv 1 \pmod{100\,000}$ (again, by Euler's theorem). Therefore $a^{40\,000} \equiv 9\,376 \pmod{100\,000}$: the last five digits of $a^{40\,000}$ are $09\,376$, which includes $0$.

**Case 4:** $a = 5^b \cdot c$, where $c$ is not divisible by $2$ or $5$. Then $p=4\,000$ works. First, we check that $5^{4\,000} \equiv 625 \pmod{10\,000}$. Next, we check that $625^2 \equiv 625 \pmod{10\,000}$; it follows that $(5^b)^{4\,000} \equiv 625^b \equiv 625 \pmod{10\,000}$ by induction. Meanwhile, $c^{4\,000} \equiv 1 \pmod{10\,000}$ (again, by Euler's theorem). Therefore $a^{4\,000} \equiv 625 \pmod{10\,000}$: the last four digits of $a^{4\,000}$ are $0\,625$, which includes $0$.

---

This proves that $p$ exists for every $a$, and in fact the smallest $p$ that works is always at most $40\,000$ (so this is an upper bound on every term of https://oeis.org/A071531).

As pointed out by Sil in the comments, we can actually do better and prove $p=2500$ works for all $a$.

- When $\gcd(a,10)=1$, we work modulo $50000$: the [Carmichael lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of $50000$ is $2500$, so we always get $a^{2500} \equiv 1$. In particular, returning to modulo $100000$, we get either $1$ or $50001$.
- When $\gcd(a,10)=2$, we multiply this by some power of $2^{2500}$ .We have $2^{2500} \equiv 9376 \pmod{100000}$. Multiplying $1$ or $50001$ by $9376$ gives $9376$ modulo $100000$, and multiplying by $9376$ more times keeps the same value.
- When $\gcd(a,10)=5$, we multiply this by some power of $5^{2500}$ .We have $5^{2500} \equiv 40625 \pmod{100000}$. Multiplying $1$ or $50001$ by $40625$ gives either $40625$ or $90625$, and multiplying these by $40625$ more times just swaps these two values.
- When $\gcd(a,10)=10$, we get lots of zeroes at the end as usual.

So the last five digits of $a^{2500}$ are always either $00\,000$, $00\,001$, $50\,001$, $09\,376$, $40\,625$, or $90\,625$, and all of these contain a zero.

For all known cases, much smaller values of $p$ work, but proving this seems very hard.

Comment: Brilliant! Btw you can push the common limit down to $p=2500$, provided that $a^{2500} \equiv 1, 50001 \pmod{10^5}$ is shown somehow for $(a,10)=1$ (the rest seems to be straightforward I think).

Comment: That should be doable: $\lambda(100\,000) = 2500$, where $\lambda(n)$ is the Carmichael lambda, so $a^{2500} \equiv 1 \pmod{100\,000}$ for all $a$ coprime to $10$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\lambda(50\,000) = 2500$, I got a bit carried away. That is exactly what guarantees us either $1$ or $50\,001$.